# Every file could be converted to UTF-8 without any errors?

Tags: utf-8

When I'm using `iconv` sometimes happens that I receive

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position <position>
```

because the `from` character is not in `to` encoding.

If I have `-t UTF-8` then I cannot receive the error message above, right?

Answer (score 1):

You will get the `illegal input sequence` error if either (a) your input is not in the specified input encoding or (b) your output encoding does not support a character in the input encoding.  So, even if you are converting to UTF-8 you may still see the error if your input stream is corrupt.

You can use `//IGNORE` to mitigate the first case and `//TRANSLIT` to mitigate the second.

Comment: if the input is correct and the output encoding is UTF-8, then I will not receive the error message, right?